# View only the login user data in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

I have a leave_applications table and an employees table. When an employee applies for a leave that is stored in leave_applications table along with employee id.
When next time employee logs in I am displaying leave applications he has applied for so far. But the problem is all leave applications are being displayed (even from other employees) which should not be the case. So how to I restrict that only the logged in employee sees his leave applications?
My LeaveApplicationsController.php page is this which displays leaves:

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->LeaveApplication->recursive = 0;
        $leavereqs = $this->set('leaveApplications', $this->Paginator->paginate());
        //return $this->LeaveApplication->Employee->find('all', array('conditions' => array('LeaveApplications.employee_id'=>$this->Auth->user('id'))));
        return $this->LeaveApplication->find('all');
        //echo $log_user_id = $this->Auth->user('role'); die();
        //return $this->LeaveApplication->Employee->query("SELECT * FROM leave_applications WHERE employee_id = '$log_user_id'");
        //return $this->LeaveApplication->Employee->query("SELECT la.leave_type, la.subject, la.detail, la.from_date, la.to_date, la.applied_on, la.leave_status, la.leave_status_date FROM leave_applications la INNER JOIN employees e ON la.employee_id = e.id INNER JOIN users u ON e.user_id = u.id WHERE la.employee_id = '$log_user_id'");
    }
```

Please note that I have this code in LeaveApplicationsController.php not in EmployeesController.php because when employee clicks on all leaves button/link this controller's index view is called.
Commented code is what I tried but none of them are working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the employee ID from Auth is ok.

Query the leave table, where the employee_is is the logged in user

```
$employeeId = $this->Auth->user('id');
return $this->LeaveApplication->findAllByEmployeeId($employeeId);
```

Comment: findAllByEmployeeId()? Is it a valid CakePHP function, because result is still the same. But still thanks for your answer

Comment: when the function name starts with "findAllBy", it will try to identify the field you want to search and make the coresponding query. Does `$employeeId` have the correct value? (`debug($employeeId`). Are you sure you have data in the database for that ID ?

Comment: Yes you are right. I was not getting proper employee id. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

index function must something like:

```
public function index()
        {   
            $id = "GET EMPLOYEE ID FROM SESSION OR BY PASSING ARGUMENT";
            $this->LeaveApplication->recursive = 0;
            $conditions = array("employee.id" => "$id");
            $leavereqs = $this->set('leaveApplications', 
                           $this->Paginator->paginate('MODEL NAME', $conditions)
                          );

        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but no records are being shown even of logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

To get leave applications of the logged in Employee, you should specify the Employee_id in your find function:

```
public function index(){

  //Make sure the Employee is logged in
  $id = $this->Auth->user('id');
  if($id){

     // get leave applications of logged in Employee
     $leavereqs = $this->LeaveApplication->find('all', array(
         'conditions'=> array('Employee_id'=>$id)
    ));

    $this->set('leavereqs',$leavreqs');
  }
}
```

If it doesn't work for you, Debug the $this->Auth->user() and make sure that in your database you assign Employee_id to leave applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can use magic find types like this:

```
findAllByEmployeeId($emp_id)
```

only in case when your field name in database is employee_id. 
Another way of getting data is :

```
find('all',array('conditions' => array('employee_id' => $emp_id));
```